# Adding .NET assembly to GAC during conversion

Tags: desktop-bridge

My installer uses Fusion API to add an assembly to GAC during conversion (using Desktop App Converter 2.0.2). When I start converted app after installation, receive "class not registered" exception when loading this COM-visible assembly.

Have anyone had a similar issue and have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: According to [Prepare to package an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare) `In the current release, your app cannot expose GAC assemblies for use by processes originating from executables external to your Windows app package`.

Comment: I'm not trying to expose the assembly to any external app - the assembly can't be used from my own app.